# How to have content-width when using display 'grid'?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following container:

```
#containerDiv {
  display: 'grid'
  grid-template-columns: 'repeat(6, auto)'
}
```

Problem Is that the children take more space than their actual width.

I want 6 child divs to be aligned but the width should be decided by the content, I don't want to set a min/max.

Imagine the following:

```
<div id="#containerDiv">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

I want the width to be the content width and then I can use margins/paddings on each child to style it to what I want. How do I accomplish this?

Code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/57aqo32t/1/

Comment: what you are describing is not a grid. A simple inline-block to your elements and your done. no need grid or flexbox

Comment: try `display: inline-grid;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the grid system, and just do this:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```